# asp.net using pagination with repeater

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

I wanted to create pagination for my reapeater. In database I have posts. I want to display firstly logged in users posts and then the rest (for example 40 per site).

I wonder if there is a way to retreive from database rows form 40 to 80 or from 80 to 120.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: check this out for paging using sql sp: http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37629.aspx

Comment: yes but how to force sql to set first rows with userId = LoggedInUserId ?

Comment: hmm you could use order by 'logged in user id' ASC

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your table has following columns: `ID, UserID, PostedDate, Subject`
Then query may look like the one below:

```
DECLARE @LoggedInUserID int,
        @RowsPerPage int,
        @PageNum int;

SELECT  @LoggedInUserID = 1,
        @RowsPerPage = 10,
        @PageNum = 1; 

with BlogPostCTE
AS
(
    select 
    bp.ID,
    bp.UserID,
    bp.PostedDate,
    CASE WHEN bp.UserID = @LoggedInUserID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as IsLoggedInUser,
    bp.[Subject]
    from BlogPost as bp
), BlogPostWithPagingCTE
AS
(
    Select Top(@RowsPerPage * @PageNum)
    ResultNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IsLoggedInUser desc, UserID, PostedDate asc),
    ID,
    UserID,
    PostedDate,
    IsLoggedInUser,
    [Subject]
    FROM BlogPostCTE
)

select
    ID,
    UserID,
    PostedDate,
    [Subject]
FROM BlogPostWithPagingCTE
where ResultNum > ((@PageNum - 1) * @RowsPerPage)
```